# Get all files those were last checked in by username

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I need to see which are the files my colleague (username = `aahan`) has checked in last time. Means all the files that have last checked in username as `aahan` in their history.

Answer (score 0):

The SourceSafe API (Microsoft.VisualStudio.SourceSafe.Interop for VSS2005 or SourceSafeTypeLib in SSAPI.DLL for VSS6) exposes a number of [methods and properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop(v=vs.90).aspx) which you can use to enumerate through a VS project to check each item and read the item history. From there you can then check which user added that [item history](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop.ivssversion_members(v=vs.90).aspx).

Here is some sample VB.NET code that will enumerate through versions of items in a project.

```
Sub CheckVSS
    Dim project As VSSItem
    Dim vssDB As VSSDatabase
    vssDB = New VSSDatabase
    vssDB.Open(sourceSafeIniPath, vssUsername, vssPassword)

    project = _vssDB.VSSItem(vssProjectFolder)
    GetHistory(project)

End Sub

Sub GetHistory(ByVal item As VSSItem)

    '--Enumerate through each version of this item. 
    For Each ver As VSSVersion In item.Versions
        Debug.Print("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", item.Name, item.Spec, ver.Username, ver.Comment)
    Next

    '--Recursively enumerate through each item in this folder and child folders. 
    For Each subitem As VSSItem In item.Items
        For Each ver As VSSVersion In subitem.Versions
            Debug.Print("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", subitem.Name, subitem.Spec, ver.Username, ver.Comment)
        Next
        GetHistory(subitem)
    Next

End Sub
```